# Drupal search does not index all nodes?

Tags: php, search, drupal-6, drupal-search

I created many nodes (Drupal 6.2x) by using script to directly insert content into the database.  The nodes themselves contain php script to get content from a database table.  All node show up as expected, and all node titles are searchable.  But, the content of most of the nodes are not searchable.  However, some of the nodes content is searchable.  I have done most of the suggested troubleshooting (clear cache, run cron manually, see if php is failing, [solving cron issues](http://drupal.org/node/553430), [does not index my custom nodes!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800852/drupal-search-engine-does-not-index-my-custom-nodes) etc) with no success.  All suggestions are welcome.  Most of the site is done, and full search is critical for release.  Thank you.

Comment: Is the non-indexed content the same as the content that is pulled dynamically by the nodes from the database?

Comment: Yes.  However, the content of some of the dynamically created nodes are searchable.

Comment: Are you able to identify any distinction between the nodes with dynamic content that are indexed and those that are not?

Answer (score 2):

I usually have similar issues with Drupal search, this module tends to fix most of the problems:

http://drupal.org/project/fuzzysearch